# List inside detail card of Ext.NestedList

Tags: sencha-touch-2

my application receives data from the database.

The "Recipes" contains **Ext.NestedList**.

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#VovtL#o7GJJ

I need to display a list inside detailed card:

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#4hKD8#uZlr7

The values ​​in the list should be taken from the base and dependent upon the key values ​​in nestedlist. 
I looked Kitchen Sink Example, but there is little that I could understand. Is it possible to implement? or better to replace nestedlist with set of buttons?
I'll be glad to get any idea.

Comment: why did you upload 2 fiddles?

Comment: to demonstrate the type of list which must be contained. And to show that the second list also contains a detailed card that is loaded from json file

Comment: So are you trying to achieve the same functionality, but with a list on the left and a detail card on the same screen? If so,there is an example here by rdougan here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708945/how-to-embed-a-nestedlist-in-a-tabpanel that does that but with inline data. I would like to adapt it to your example with data from a JSON file but I haven't been able to do it yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
onLeafItemTap: function(nestedList, list, index, node, record, e) {
        var detailCard = nestedList.getDetailCard();
        detailCard.removeAll(true, false);
        detailCard.setHtml('');
        detailCard.setLayout('fit');
        var urList = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
            fullscreen: true,
            itemTpl: '{title}',
            data: [
                { title: 'Item 1' },
                { title: 'Item 2' },
                { title: 'Item 3' },
                { title: 'Item 4' }
            ]
        });
        detailCard.add(urList);
    }
```

the code is quite self explainatory. you just have to replace urList with your list. and change the store.. 
if any problem let me know