# Split view in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, ipad

I am making application for IPAD and I need to show split view there.

What is my requirement in this:

I will show a list in left panel (Data will not be for nested. I have only 1 level)

When I click on any item of list, it will load a another list in right panel.

In right panel , if I click on any item, it will show the detail page in the same view.

Can any one give me a working example for it?

Comment: That might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708945/how-to-embed-a-nestedlist-in-a-tabpanel

Comment: I have seen the above example earlier and that is using the tab panel and I don't want it.

Comment: then just remove it..